# NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID in Chrome/Opera on Linux

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, self-signed

I have set up a self-signed CA in a development environment and have issued a server certificate to a test website.

The issue I'm having is that the certificate is being rejected by the browser with NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID

This only happens with Chrome or Opera in Linux (Opensuse Leap 15.2). I've tested the same site on Windows 10 with Chrome/FireFox/Edge/Internet Explorer/Opera - all of them are successful. In Windows the CA was imported into the Trusted Roots for the User (perhaps there is something similar on Linux?)

On Linux only Firefox works, Chrome and Opera fail with the same error. Unfortunately Linux is the desktop used most.

To debug the issue I started a Wireshark trace whilst connecting to the site, what I'm seeing is Certificate Unknown (46) error

[image: Wireshark trace]

[image]

I'm really not sure what can be causing this and so specifically with Chrome/Opera on Linux.

The server side is NGINX and the certificates are configured as follows:

```
ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/pki/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/pki/server.key;
```

Where server.crt is a concatenation of the server cert and the CA cert (server first).

Any ideas what's causing this or what I can do next to debug further?

Comment: In short: you need to add the root CA to all relevant CA stores and  browsers might use their own and not the system one.

Answer (score 0):

> In Windows the CA was imported into the Trusted Roots for the User
> (perhaps there is something similar on Linux?)

Yes, there is.  The method varies by distribution, but you'll want to add your self-signed CA to the appropriate directory and run the appropriate update script.  [Here's an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90450/adding-a-self-signed-certificate-to-the-trusted-list) which outlines both Debian-ish and RedHat methods for adding a CA.

Comment: This link only addresses the CA as used by tools like curl. Chrome and Firefox have IMHO their own CA stores, thus adding the certificate to the system CA store will not help.

Comment: Firefox still uses their own CA store; however [Chrome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77822/66633) and [Opera](https://superuser.com/a/983021/280122) have both shifted to using the system store for their certs.